# Obfuscating Monogame assets

Tags: c#, monogame, assets, security

I'm obfuscating spritesheets. I've already encrypted the .txt file dictionaries. Now I'd like to perform binary serialization on the image files. `Texture2D` does not allow for this though, probably because it's coupled to the `ContentManager` and by extension the `Graphicsdevice`.

The solution I'd like to go for would be serializing the image files in a single wrapper object in the obfuscation code, and deserializing it when the game is loading. However, `Content.Load<Texture2D>()` will only take the asset name as parameter. Is there a workaround, or am I looking at this problem the wrong way?

Comment: You could always write your own Content Pipeline extension.

Comment: You can always do Texture2D.fromStream. Load up the encrypted file, decrypt it, throw it into a memory stream, and finally load it into the Texture2D via to fromStream method. Curious why this is deemed necessary though? There is little to gain in client side security. Considering its C# they can decompile your program and use it to decrypt the assets, most likely rather trivially.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Will that work? I'm under the impression you can only add types - not modify the available formats of existing types.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Well... you defeat bog-standard XNB readers. So it raises the bar to people who can decompile. And then, if you obfuscate your assembly, it raises the bar even further. Further still if you only target, say, iOS. So it's not *completely* without merit.

Comment: @AndrewRussell More than doubting the effectivness, I doubt the need.

Comment: @AndrewRussell I was thinking of a specific new type, like 'EncryptedTexture2D'.

Comment: I ended up using Texture2D.FromStream(), where the stream is a Memorystream that has been written to by a CryptoStream, which in part read from an encrypted image file.

As for why I'm doing this - I'm only targeting iOS, and I simply don't want any user to go into the asset files and make modifications. You're never entirely safe of course, but this barrier should repel 99% of those who even try.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the ideal extension point for something like this is to inherit from `ContentManager`. [Here is a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx) (for XNA) that explains how to use `ReadAsset` to change the caching policy (not what you want).

What you probably want to do is inherit from `ContentManager` and override `OpenStream`. Then simply implement obfuscation at the stream level (ie: obfuscate the entire asset file).

Alternately you could just override `Load` and handle `Texture2D` explicitly to do whatever you want. You could, for instance, call `ReadAsset<ObfuscatedTexture2D>(...)` and then construct a `Texture2D` instance yourself and return that.

If you're creating the texture yourself, you'll need a graphics device to load it onto. It can be accessed through the `ContentManager.ServiceProvider` property. Like so:

```
var gds = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService)) as IGraphicsDeviceService;
var graphicsDevice = gds.GraphicsDevice;
```

(Note: This will work in XNA. It should work in MonoGame, but if not... [use the source](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Content/ContentManager.cs).)